# Access video using localIdentifier, swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, phasset, photokit

I want to open a video, for which I have the localIdentifier. I know I can create an AVPlayer like this,

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
```

Is it possible to open a video by providing its localIdentifier?

I am using the video as a PHAsset to obtain its localIdentifier. It is possible to use PHFetchOptions and fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers, however, it would be like a query. Is there a more direct way to access a video or an image if I have its localIdentifier?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestPlayerItemForVideo:options:resultHandler:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestAVAssetForVideo:options:resultHandler:

Comment: thanks, requestPlayerItemForVideo should work

Comment: how do I use localIdentifier in PHVideoRequestOptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to present a video asset in an `AVPlayer`, the best thing to request from Photos for providing to the player is an `AVPlayerItem`. Supposing you have the `localIdentifier` for a video asset in the Photos library, you'll need to first find the `PHAsset` representing that asset:

```
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers([identifier], options: nil)
guard let asset = assets.firstObject as? PHAsset
    else { fatalError("no asset") }
```

Once you have a `PHAsset` you can use `PHImageManager` to fetch the asset's video content (in the form of an `AVPlayerItem`):

```
let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
options.networkAccessAllowed = true
let requestID = PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestPlayerItemForVideo(asset, 
    options: options, 
    resultHandler: { playerItem, info in
        guard let item = playerItem
            else { fatalError("can't get player item: \(info)") }

        // send the item to whatever you're playing AV content with, e.g.
        myAVPlayerViewController.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    }
)
```